# Problem with team fortress 2

Tags: 11.10, playonlinux, steam

When I'm trying to play Team Fortress 2 by Playonlinux after loading server there is error ,,Internal error invalid parameters received". How can I solve this problem.
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

`-windowed -noborder`  in launch options
might work.